# How to keep method names in Android Proguard R8?

Tags: android, proguard, android-r8

I'm developing an Android Library and I'd like to have this result for Proguard.

- I want to keep all package names, which I'm using "-keeppackagenames" to achieve.
- I want to keep all class names.
- I want to keep method names and method argument names for all public methods.

Other than that, I'd like to obfuscate and shrink everything else, including but not limited to all of non-public methods and even the body of the public methods.

How can I achieve that result?

Thank you very much beforehand for your help!

Answer (score 1):

R8 itself is distributes as a library which has been run through R8. For that library we want to achieve exactly what you ask to ensure that developers using the library will not by accident use any APIs which are not supposed to be public (this has nothing to do with protecting IP as the project is open source).

The rules can be found [here](https://r8.googlesource.com/r8/+/b828ec1cc5c612d7dba4af32b0edcd7316241695/src/main/keep.txt) and I will explain the rationale for them below.

We try to be indirect and use annotations, so the main rules are:

```
-keep @com.android.tools.r8.Keep class * { public *; }
-keep @com.android.tools.r8.KeepForSubclassing class * { public *; protected *; }
```

All API classes are then annotated with [`@Keep`](https://r8.git.corp.google.com/r8/+/b828ec1cc5c612d7dba4af32b0edcd7316241695/src/main/java/com/android/tools/r8/D8Command.java#52) or [`@KeepForSubclassing`](https://r8.git.corp.google.com/r8/+/b828ec1cc5c612d7dba4af32b0edcd7316241695/src/main/java/com/android/tools/r8/ProgramResourceProvider.java#9).

Then a number of attrubutes are kept

```
-keepattributes SourceFile, LineNumberTable, InnerClasses, EnclosingMethod, Exceptions, Signature
```

`SourceFile` and `LineNumberTable` are kept to get [retracable stack traces](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code?authuser=1#decode-stack-trace). The rest for javac compilation and IDE integration for library users.

Then

```
-keepparameternames
```

is there for IDE integration getting the names of arguments in the API, and

```
-keeppackagenames com.android.tools.r8
-repackageclasses com.android.tools.r8.internal
```

to move as many classes as possible into the `internal` name space so the renamed classes does not show up in IDE's.

There are a few additional rules in the file to handle cases not covered by the annotation based approach.

Comment: The link to the keep file you post here uses Googles internal system, would it be possible to convert it to a public one?

Comment: Sure, thanks for reporting this. Updated to https://r8.googlesource.com/r8/+/b828ec1cc5c612d7dba4af32b0edcd7316241695/src/main/keep.txt.